# Getting crash on UITabBarController.selectedIndex

Tags: swift, uitabbarcontroller

I'm getting crash on "UITabBarController.selectedIndex". Tab bar is not getting nil at any time of the execution that is the surprising fact and still getting error on that particular line. Please guide me through proper solution.

```
        let obj = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("OfferViewController") as! OfferViewController
        setFlagWhilePushingFromMenuViewController()

        obj.screenName = SCREEN.MOBILE_RECHARGE.rawValue
        rechargeManager.presentRechargeScreen = PRESENT_SCREEN.MOBILE.rawValue

        if let tab : UITabBarController = self.revealViewController().frontViewController as? UITabBarController{
            let index : Int =  tab.selectedIndex // CRASH POINT
            print("----->\(tab.selectedIndex)")

            tab.selectedIndex = 1
            let navig : UINavigationController = tab.viewControllers![index] as! UINavigationController

            navig.pushViewController(obj, animated: true)
            self.revealViewController().revealToggleAnimated(true)
        }
        else{
            print("do something else")
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

To get selectedIndex of tabar, apply below code,

```
var application: AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
var tabbarController = application.tabBarController as UITabBarController
var selectedIndex = tabBarController!.selectedIndex
```

You will get selectedIndex like this. Its working here.